# Pyscript on click

Tags: python-3.x, pyscript

i want to use pyscript to do a login/register website but he don't wark the code:

```
<div>
    <button type="button" id="shuffle" pys-OnClcik="run"><span></span>LOG IN</button>
    <button type="button2" id="shuffle2" pys-OnClick="run"><span></span>REGISTRATI </button>
</div>

<script defer src="https://pyscript.net/alpha/pyscript.js"></script>

<pyscript>
import webbrowser

def run(*args):
    pyscript.write("button" "salve")
    print("don't work")

</pyscript>
```

---

Thanks to all of the help you have given me but given the fact that pyscript is still in the growth phase I decided to learn javascript for these issues in the sites

Comment: Use the browser debugger and post the errors in your question.

Comment: Note: Since you are using events, you must import the `asyncio` library.